# KeyError occurs even though column exists

Tags: python, pandas, csv, indexing, keyerror

I'm aware that this question is asked a lot on here but I've been looking through the other questions and I haven't found any which used a .csv file.

Here is my csv file:

> ```
> Survived, Pclass, Sex, Age, Siblings, Parents, Fare  
> 0, 3, male, 22.0, 1, 0, 7.25  
> 1, 1, female, 38.0, 1, 0, 71.2833  
> 1,3,female, 26.0, 0, 0, 7.925  
> 1, 1, female, 35.0, 1, 0, 53.1
> ```

And my code:

```
import pandas as pd  
df = pd.read_csv("titanic.csv")  
print(df)  
print(df.columns)  
print(df["Pclass"])
```

Lines 3 and 4 of my code work perfectly, so there probably isn't an issue with the second line or with the csv file itself, right? Line 5 is where it goes wrong. This is the error message:
[image: This is the error message.]

What's strange is that when I try to do line 5 with 'Survived', the first heading in the file, it works. It's only with the other headings that this error occurs.
I'm using Python version 3.7.1 and pandas version 1.0.3 if that helps.

Comment: You got a space before your Column name.... `print(df[" Pclass"])`

Comment: Include the output of `print(df.columns) ` in your question. You'll probably see some extra whitespace that needs trimming.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think it's fixed now! That was such a simple solution.

Answer (score 4):

The default delimiter in `read_csv` is a comma (`,`). Your CSV file uses a comma and a space (`,`). You need to explicitly specify this delimiter:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("titanic.csv", sep=', ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to `strip()` your columns like below so it will remove the whitespaces.

```
print(df)  
print(df.columns)  
df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip(), inplace=True)
print(df["Pclass"])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have whitespace alongside your column names. Your column is not `Pclass` but  `Pclass`.

check this:

```
print(df[" Pclass"])
```

if you want to strip your column names out of white space, you could do this.

```
df.rename(columns={c: c.strip() for c in df.columns}, inplace=True)
```